# Server Side Logging Of Client Side Javascript Crashes

Tags: javascript, logging, remote-debugging

I have a large complex web app with thousands of lines of Javascript. There is a small set of intermittent Javascript bugs that are report by users.

I think these are epiphenomena of race conditions - something has not initialised correctly and the Javascript crashes causing 'down stream' js not to run.

Is there anyway to get Javascript execution crashes to log back server side?

All the js logging libraries like [Blackbird](http://www.gscottolson.com/blackbirdjs/) and [Log4JavaScript](http://log4javascript.org/) are client-side only.

Comment: If the bugs cause errors to be thrown, you could look into `window.onerror` and send an ajax request inside the handler (sending the event argument along). This of course wouldn't work if the app really crashes (as in a browser crash).

Comment: @pimvdb that should be an answer :)

Comment: @JaniHartikainen I agree

Comment: If Javascript in the browser is single-threaded, is it still a "race condition", or do you call it something else when AJAX responses come back in a different order than expected?

Comment: the answer by @Bhavin does almost exactly what you need

Answer (score 3):

I have written a remote error logging function using window.onerror as suggested by @pimvdb

```
Err = {};

Err.Remoterr = {};

Err.Remoterr.onerror = function (msg, errorfileurl, lineno) {

    var jsonstring, response, pageurl, cookies;

    // Get some user input
    response = prompt("There has been an error. " +
                      "It has been logged and will be investigated.", 
                      "Put in comments (and e-mail or phone number for" + 
                      " response.)");

    // get some context of where and how the error occured
    // to make debugging easier
    pageurl = window.location.href;
    cookies = document.cookie;

    // Make the json message we are going to post
    // Could use JSON.stringify() here if you are sure that
    // JSON will have run when the error occurs
    // http://www.JSON.org/js.html
    jsonstring = "{\"set\": {\"jserr\": " +
        "{\"msg\": \""         + msg + "\", " + 
        "\"errorfileurl\": \"" + errorfileurl + "\", " +
        "\"pageurl\": \""      + pageurl + "\", " +
        "\"cookies\": \""      + cookies + "\", " +
        "\"lineno\": \""       + lineno + "\", " +
        "\"response\": \""     + response + "\"}}}";

    // Use the jquery cross-browser post
    // http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/
    // this assumes that no errors happen before jquery has initialised
    $.post("?jserr", jsonstring, null, "json");

    // I don't want the page to 'pretend' to work 
    // so I am going to return 'false' here
    // Returning 'true' will clear the error in the browser
    return false;
};

window.onerror = Err.Remoterr.onerror;
```

I deploy this between the **head** and **body** tags of the webpage.

You will want to change the JSON and the URL that you post it to depending on how you are going to log the data server side.

Comment: +1 If you use jQuery though, you can also pass an object instead of messing with escaping etc (just for clarity). It will automatically serialize it.

Comment: @pimvdb - the gift that keeps on giving. Our code base uses JSON.stringify() throughout. I wanted to keep the error code as slim as possible so I did it manually :(

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at https://log4sure.com (disclosure: I created it) - but it is really useful, check it out and decide for yourself. It allows you to log errors/event and also lets you create your custom log table. It also allows you to monitor your logs real-time. And the best part, its free.

You can also use bower to install it, use bower install log4sure

The set up code is really easy too:

```js
// setup
var _logServer;

(function() {
  var ls = document.createElement('script');
  ls.type = 'text/javascript';
  ls.async = true;
  ls.src = 'https://log4sure.com/ScriptsExt/log4sure.min.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(ls, s);
  ls.onload = function() {
    // use your token here.
    _logServer = new LogServer("use-your-token-here");
  };
})();

//  example for logging text
_logServer.logText("your log message goes here.")

//example for logging error 
divide = function(numerator, divisor) {
    try {
      if (parseFloat(value) && parseFloat(divisor)) {
        throw new TypeError("Invalid input", "myfile.js", 12, {
          value: value,
          divisor: divisor
        });
      } else {
        if (divisor == 0) {
          throw new RangeError("Divide by 0", "myfile.js", 15, {
            value: value,
            divisor: divisor
          });
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      _logServer.logError(e.name, e.message, e.stack);

    }
  }
  // another use of logError in window.onerror
  // must be careful with window.onerror as you might be overwriting some one else's window.onerror functionality
  // also someone else can overwrite window.onerror.
window.onerror = function(msg, url, line, column, err) {
  // may want to check if url belongs to your javascript file
  var data = {
    url: url,
    line: line,
    column: column,

  }
  _logServer.logError(err.name, err.message, err.stack, data);

};

// example for custom logs
var foo = "some variable value";
var bar = "another variable value";
var flag = "false";
var temp = "yet another variable value";

_logServer.log(foo, bar, flag, temp);
```